# :value="form.name | slugify" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have a value i want to save to the database as a slug generated from the name. The problem is I cannot use both v-model and :value in the same input field. what is the solution to this? I am using laravel and vuejs. How can i solve this error?

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Slug</label>
                    <input v-model="form.slug" :value="form.name | slugify" type="text" name="slug" 
                        placeholder="downtown-dubai" 
                        class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('slug') }">
                    <has-error :form="form" field="slug"></has-error>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate slug from the name on the backend. 
From the Frontend, you only send `name` and other needed fields, while on the backend you use that `name` to create a slug.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most direct way would by to use `v-model="form.name"` and get rid of the `:value` attribute, then just update `form.slug` using the data from `form.name` in the function that submits the form.  Example:

```
submitForm() {
    this.form.slug = this.$options.filters.slugify(this.form.name)
    // Submit the form...
},
```

If the `form.slug` field is actually displayed on the page and needs to immediately be reactive, you could also update it using a watcher for `form.name` like this.

```
watch: {
    'form.name'() {
        this.form.slug = this.$options.filters.slugify(this.form.name)
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the watcher worked like a charm.